# Solving modular system involving binomial coefficients. Does there even exist a solution?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, binomial-coefficients

Consider the following system:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k =0\space (even)}^{n}{n \choose k} \sqrt{7}^{k} &= 0 \pmod{u}\\
\sum\limits_{k=0 \space (odd)}^{n}{n \choose k} \sqrt{7}^{k-1} &= 1\pmod{u}\end{align*}$$

For a given $u$, how can I determine whether this system has a solution? This means:

1. Does the system even have a solution?
2. How can one determine a $n$ for what it has a solution?

Comment: Closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4072878/242) the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the second equation by $\sqrt{7},$ and add the two equations together, to get

$$(1+\sqrt{7})^n \equiv (1+\sqrt{7}) \mod u.$$, so
$$(1+\sqrt{7})^{n-1}\equiv 1 \mod u.$$

So, if $7$ is a quadratic residue mod $u$ and $n-1$ is *not* divisible by $\phi(u),$ there is no solution.

Comment: And for determining solutions to this system one just has to "brute force" them in a sense?